# Extraction only portion of localStorage

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and I am trying to extract only a portion of the inputID (i.e., last 4 digits of item) but it is not working.

Without the "var last4 = localStorage.userInfo.substr(-4);", it pulls the item.

Complete script below:

```
localStorage.clear();

function storeText(inputID) {
    var userInput = localStorage.userInfo;

    if(userInput!=null) {
        userInput+=" ";
    } 
    else { 
        userInput=""; 
    }

    userInput += document.getElementById(inputID).value;

    localStorage.userInfo = userInput;

    document.getElementById("nicky").innerHTML = localStorage.userInfo;

    var last4 = localStorage.userInfo.substr(-4);
}
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the `last4` variable. How do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your `last4` variable will contain the last 4 characters, you need to do something with that variable to display it.

```js
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var last4 = userInput.substr(-4);
    document.getElementById("nicky").innerHTML = last4;
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="userInput" value="123456789"/>
</div>

<div>
  Last 4 Characters: <span id="nicky"></span>
</div>
```